# Open source document management system

Tags: java, open-source, document-management, dms

I have evaluated couple of Open source document management system and it seems that these are in old days e.g.[opendocman](http://www.opendocman.com/),[quotero](http://www.quotero.com/)

I am looking for a open source document management system which provides me below features.

- Should keep data on the same machine as I am looking for more of internal purpose.
- Should allow to upload Zip files as well. If it extracts Zip it will be a great +
- Should allow to send email to preconfigured email addresses
- Should allow to upload data of size around 100MB at one go
- Should maintain history of documents also deleted documents
- Should allow role based document access.
- **Should be Free :)**
- It should not do any spoofing on data. Documents are confidential.
- Should support 32 bit Linux version. [Alfresco: 64 bit only]

Please let me know if you have experience in using anyone and if I can use it?

Comment: These are paid systems. If google would have helped I wouldn't have to come to SO. Trials are Free. That is why I was looking for some one who has used open source free document management system.

Comment: They all have free versions - if you had spent a few minutes on either you would have found the link(s). StackOverflow is not a replacement for Google. It is a place to ask _programming related questions_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you consider to use **[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/)** ?

- It is open source document management system even you can use it even
  in cloud.
- It can give 10GB for using in cloud.
- It should allow to upload Zip files as well.
- It should allow to send email to preconfigured email addresses.
- But I am not sure for maintaining history deleted documents but it
  maintains document history.
- Also have role base document access.
- **Free** use for alfresco software.

Comment: I am trying Free version of Alfresco if it does not do any spoofing I will accept this answer.

Comment: It does not have linux 32 bit version. Lets see I can use custom components.

Comment: https://tpeelen.wordpress.com/2012/01/04/installing-alfresco-3-x-4-x-on-32bit-ubuntu/

Comment: Ahh Looks are not that great but I guess You can not ask more for free :)